# Secure option for inserting encrypted data into linked server - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have a database hosted on one server which has a linked server connection to another server which houses data for a custom application. The database with the linked server connection needs to insert sensitive data from a table into the database hosted on the linked server for the custom application.

I followed this guide (https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2431/sql-server-column-level-encryption-example-using-symmetric-keys/) and created the symmetric key on the server which is used for the custom application and I can insert and read encrypted data fine on the custom application server.

[image]

As you can see in Step 3 above, i create a MASTER KEY in the database on the custom application server. What I want to do now, is use:

```
INSERT INTO LinkedServer.Table
SELECT EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('myKey'), someColumn), etc
FROM SensitiveData.Table
```

After all of that, my question is, since this key only exists on the linked server used for the custom application, I get an error when trying to EncryptByKey on the INSERT from the sensitive data server to custom application server with the message:

> Remote function reference 'LinkedServer.DatabaseName.dbo.EncryptByKey'
>   is not allowed, and the column name 'LinkedServer' could not be found
>   or is ambiguous.

Should I create the same Key on the sensitive data server so it can encrypt from there and is there any security risk in doing that? Or is there some syntaxual way to tell it to use the key on the linked server to do the encryption? Or a final way I thought to do it was create another table in the custom application server, insert the data from the sensitive data server as it normally appears, put a trigger on that table and After Insert, use the Master Key on the custom application server to encrypt the data, move it into the table I want the encrypted data saved in, and delete it from the new table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I tackled this issue.

> 1. I created a temp table in my linked server database to hold the plain text data.
> 2. I set an AFTER INSERT trigger on the temp table to insert into the encrypted table using the MASTER KEY on the linked server to encrypt all the values.
> 3. Deleted all data from the temp table.

This gets the job done, I'm still unsure of whether I approached this situation correctly, so feel free to comment or add an answer to this post.